# Google Cloud Platform (GCP): How to give additional roles to service account?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

How can I give additional roles to the default Google App Engine (GAE) service account:

Specifically, I want to give "Cloud SQL client" role to the default app engine service account. When I try to modify the role I get this message:

[image]

Comment: You are in the wrong section the console. To add roles to a service account, go to `IAM & Admin` -> IAM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it was answered in the comment section by *@John Hanley*, to add roles to a service account, go to `IAM & Admin` -> `IAM`, find your service account in the table and edit it to grant necessary roles.

In addition, please have a look st the documentation [Understanding service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts) section [Granting access to service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts#granting_access_to_service_accounts):

> Granting access to a service account to access a resource is similar
> to granting access to any other identity. For example, if you have an
> application running on Compute Engine and you want the application to
> *only* have access to create objects in Cloud Storage. You can create a service account for the application and grant it the [Storage Object
> Creator](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/iam) role.

> Learn about [Granting roles to all types of members](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access), including
> service accounts.